# Integral over Fractals with respect to fractal dimension

Tags: integration, fractals, dimension-theory-analysis, fractional-calculus, dimensional-analysis

I understand that there is type of integral with respect to measures that can return values when evaluated over an integral. But is there an Integral that returns d dimensional volume where d is the fractal dimension of the fractal. Basically, I'm asking about finding an integral that can find the volume of say the cantor set in terms of $m^{ln2/ln3}$. This question is mostly motivated by the fact that the area of 2-d objects can vary a lot, yet they all have units of $m^2$. I'd assume this would be the case for fractal objects as well. As an example, if I wanted to take the integral of the siernpinski triangle and get a $ln3/ln2$ dimensional volume instead of taking the area of a square, could I? If so, could you provide a link or an explanation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\mu$ is a measure and $1_E$ is the characteristic function of a set $E$ then, in principle, 
$$\int 1_E \, d\mu$$
returns the measure $\mu(E)$.  If $\mu_s$ is an $s$-dimensional measure (like the Hausdorff or Packing measure), then I guess the integral returns what you're looking for.  I don't think that makes computing the exact value any easier, though.

If you are interested in an introduction to integration using fractal measures, I highly recommend the paper [Evaluating Integrals Using Self-similarity](http://www.maa.org/sites/default/files/pdf/mathdl/AMM/evaluatingintegrals.pdf) by Bob Strichartz.  The paper gives an excellent introduction to integration with respect to self-similar measures.

Comment: I read the paper, it was quite interesting. I also did some more research and found a couple papers on Fractal Extent, which is supposed to be a way of experimentally measuring fractional dimensional volumes. The free part, was more than enough to give me hope [Distribution of Bald Eagles](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF00384796)